# Simple question on Medical Data analysis

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

I am investigating a medical device and really it is just a proof of concept. 20 patients all with a problem (disease x) does our medical device detect disease x. Each patient undergoes one trial and the outcome is either that the problem was correctly identified or that it was missed.

What hypothesis do you think is satisfactory and what statistical analysis would be correct.

Also what would my CI really show in this example.

Comment: I think you could estimate the rate at which the device correctly identifies the disease when the disease is present.  You could also estimate the type-ii error rate, or false negative rate, that is, when the disease is present, but the device failed to detect it.  As you say, the confidence interval for these estimates would be helpful.  But it would also be helpful if you also tested the device on those without the disease.

Comment: If you want to turn this information into a hypothesis test, you could use a null hypothesis, e.g., that the device identifies the disease when present better than 50%, or, say, better than 80%.  Likewise with the false negative rate.  But it seems like computing rates and confidence intervals would be more useful.  Except maybe to include  a null null that the device is better 50/50, but this would also be clear in the confidence interval results.

Comment: Would it make sense to turn this into the following test...

H1 -> The device has 90% sensitivity in detecting disease X. 

What statistical approach would I take. 

Thank you so much!  Can I reward people on this platform?

Comment: Yes, send cash or checks to...  Just kidding.  I'll write up my thoughts as an answer shortly.  From there you can upvote or select as the accepted answer....  Well, the H1 would be more like "the detection rate† is greater than 90%", or is "not 90%".  You could do that as formal hypothesis test...  If you present the rate and the confidence interval, and that interval includes 90%, that would suggest that the rate is not different than 90%... (†): I'm avoiding "sensitivity" just because I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: As the ideal is surely that your question and any answers help others too, please edit the uninformative title to something more precise.

Comment: _Sensitivity_ is P(pos test | has disease). _Specificity_ is P(neg test | no disease).  A bogus test that  _always_ shows positive (regardless of disease state), would have sensitivity 1 and specificity 0. In practice, a trade-off btw sensitivity and specificity is sought, often by use of an OC curve

Comment: Thanks, @BruceET . I added this terminology to my answer, which was helpful.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion by @NickCox . OP: please update your question title so that it will be helpful for other readers.

Comment: Please edit your title to indicate the nature of the problem you're asking about. Telling us you need help is pointless -- we already know that, that's what everybody wants.

Answer (score 5):

I think a simple approach would be to estimate the rate at which the device correctly identifies the disease when the disease is present (*sensitivity*). You could also estimate the false negative rate; that is, when the disease is present but the device failed to detect it (*1 - sensitivity*). Including the confidence intervals for these estimates would be helpful.

But it would also be helpful if you also tested the device on those without the disease.

If you wanted to use a formal hypothesis test, the nullest of null hypotheses to test against would be *Ho: The device has a 50% chance of detecting the disease when the disease is present*. Rejecting this null hypothesis may not be very impressive to the audience, but at least does suggest that the device "works"  in some sense, especially at the proof-of-concept stage.

Proportions other than 0.50 in a null hypothesis ***could*** be tested against.  But with a (smallish) sample size of 20, you might be surprised that you may not be able to reject the null hypothesis for say, *P = 0.70* or *P = 0.80*.

For this reason, unless there is a null proportion for which there is good reason to test the measured sensitivity against, I would recommend instead using the estimate and confidence interval approach.  Or using that approach augmented with the test against the null hypothesis of *P = 0.50*.

A hypothetical example follows.  It can be run in R or at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ .

In this hypothetical example, there are 20 observations, all of which are positive for the disease in reality.  The device detects the disease in 18 of the observations, and fails to detect in 2 observations.

```
Total     = 20
Detected  = 18
Failed    = Total - Detected
```

The output for the binomial test gives us an estimate for the sensitivity (0.9); and the 95% confidence interval for this estimate (Clopper-Pearson) (0.68 to 0.99).

It also reports a *p* value for the test against the default null hypothesis, *P = 0.50* (*p* =  0.0004).

```
binom.test(Detected, Total)

   ### Exact binomial test
   ### p-value = 0.0004025
   ### 95 percent confidence interval:
   ### 0.6830173 0.9876515
   ###
   ### probability of success 
   ###                    0.9
```

We could do the same test for the count of failed observations.  The *p* value will be the same, but the results will give us the confidence interval for the proportion of failed observations.

```
binom.test(Failed, Total)

   ### 95 percent confidence interval:
   ###    0.01234853 0.31698271
```

We ***could*** test against another null hypothesis, say that *P = 0.75*.

```
binom.test(Detected, Total, p=0.75)

   ### p-value = 0.1931
   ### alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.75
```

(***Not shown here***, you could also use a one-sided hypothesis test.)

If the confidence intervals for both proportions are being presented, it is my understanding that using a method for simultaneous multinominal proportions may be more appropriate.  Here, the Sison-Glaz method is used.

```
library(DescTools)

observed = c(Detected, Failed)

MultinomCI(observed,
           conf.level=0.95,
           method="sisonglaz")

   ###      est lwr.ci    upr.ci
   ### [1,] 0.9   0.85 1.0000000
   ### [2,] 0.1   0.05 0.2485667
```

A plot of estimates and confidence intervals may be helpful.  Here, all the estimates and confidence limits are retyped manually as *X*, *Y*, *LCI*, and *UCI*.  I used the results from the Sison-Glaz method.

```
X = c("Detected", "Failed to Detect")
Y = c(0.90, 0.10)
LCI = c(0.85, 0.05)
UCI = c(1.00, 0.249)

Data = data.frame(X, Y, LCI, UCI)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data,
       aes(x     = X,
           y     = Y)) +

    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             color = "black",
             fill  = "dodgerblue",
             width =  0.7) +

    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  = LCI,
                      ymax  = UCI),
                      width = 0.2,
                      size  = 0.7,
                      color = "black"
                      ) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold")) +

    ylab("Rate\n") +
    xlab("\n")
```

[image: Bar plot of estimates]

Comment: Sal this is incredibly helpful. I posted on this website even though I am not a contributing member and am so grateful that the community (and yourself) has helped so much. This answer has largely contributed to my MHRA submission! I am useless at stats as this question shows so cannot help out others in turn - so just wanted to say a genuine thank you to yourself and all that answer! :)

Comment: No, problem, @kristian .  That's what this website is about.  We have all benefited from the understanding and generosity of those before us, and personally I have benefited greatly from searching on Cross Validated and similar sites.